# Java square root calculator?

Tags: java, square-root

Ok, I'm a beginner in java, learning on my own through websites and books. I tried a simple square root calculator with a `for` loop and a `while` loop (I've included what I tried below). Sadly, all my code does when I enter a number is terminate. Any help would be appreciated!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class The2RootProdject {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        double rootIt = input.nextDouble();
        double dummy = 0.0000000;

        while (dummy != dummy * dummy) {
            dummy += 0.0000001;
            if (rootIt == dummy * dummy) {
                System.out.println("the squar root of " + rootIt + " is "
                        + (dummy * dummy));
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: while (0 != 0*0) won't be executed, right?

Comment: A number will almost never be equal to itself times itself unless I'm missing something. That will cause the loop to immediately exit.

Comment: Well, `0` is equal to `0 * 0`, so the while loop is never entered.

Comment: if dummy is `0.0000000` then `dummy * dummy` must be equal to 0 as well, which is equal to `dummy`. Therefore the condition for the while loop is never met

Comment: The problem is that floating point numbers aren't exact:

Comment: `dummy != dummy * dummy` "should" be `rootIt != dummy * dummy` (the whole algorithm is not a good idea). Maybe you should learn to use a debugger to find problems like this by yourself.

Comment: Also In the print statement you're printing dummy * dummy as the square root instead of just dummy

Comment: It's quite unlikely that your input will have a rational square root. Consider checking whether `rootIt` is close to `dummy * dummy`, rather than exactly equal.

Comment: This is a terribly inefficient *and* inaccurate way to approximate a square root.  Have a look at [Newton's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) (or, if that looks too complicated, [bisection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection_method)) as an alternative.  You can use as an initial bracketing interval that 0 ≤ sqrt(*x*) ≤ *x* for every *x* ≥ 0.

Comment: Ok. I see what what you all mean. So do
    rootIt != dummy * dummy? or just do  Newton's method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use this algorithm which use Newton's iteration:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        double number, t, squareRoot;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        number = input.nextDouble();
        squareRoot = number / 2;
        do
        {
            t = squareRoot;
            squareRoot = (t + (number / t)) / 2;
        }
        while ((t - squareRoot) != 0);

        System.out.println(squareRoot);
    }
}
```

Newton's iteration is an algorithm for computing the square root of a number via the recurrence equation:
X(n+1) = (X(n) + number/X(n))/2

Comment: Thanks for the help! Btw, I'm new at java, so what does 'do' do?

Answer (score 6):

You have a couple of problems here:

1) Logical bug: 0 == 0 * 0

<= This means `while (dummy != dummy * dummy) {..}` will never be untrue, and you'll never even enter the loop

2) Floating point numbers are *inexact*, so your algorithm (which relies on "==") might not work anyway

Look here for more details on floating point imprecision:

http://www.lahey.com/float.htm

This is true for *ANY* language - your algorithm for square root must take this into account.

Answer (score 0):

I think the while condition is supposed to be =

```
while(rootIt != dummy * dummy) {}
```

Your current condition will only ever be true if you initialized `dummy` as 1; but I don't that would be what you want anyways.